# Slickgrid 3 grouping how to remove totals row?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap-3, slickgrid

I use multi-row grouping and put the totals in the grouping headers. 
I'm not using the totals in the totals rows.  I see the the rows are grouped and where the totals would be there are empty rows.  In my case there is an empty row after each of the child grouping and at the end there is an empty row for the parent totals.
How do I remove these totals rows?
Thank you!

.cshtml:

```
  <div id="gridList" class="grid" style="width: 100%; height: 500px"></div>
```

.js

```
$(function() {
    var columns = [
    {
        id: "isExcluded",
        name: "Exclude",
        field: "isExcluded" /*, width: 120*/,
        formatter: Slick.Formatters.Checkmark,
        editor: Slick.Editors.Checkbox, sortable: true
    },
    {
        id: "symbol",
        name: "Symbol",
        field: "symbol",
        sortable: true /*, width: 120*/
    },
    {
        id: "price",
        name: "Price",
        field: "price",
        sortable: true
        //, groupTotalsFormatter: sumTotalsFormatter 
    },
    {
        id: "parent_name",
        name: "Parent Name",
        field: "parent_name",
        sortable: true /*, width: 120*/
    },

    {
        id: "description",
        name: "Description",
        field: "description",
        sortable: true,
        width: 120,
        editor: Slick.Editors.Text,
    },
    { id: "cancel_ind", 
      name: "Canceled", 
      field: "cancel_ind", 
      sortable: true, width: 80 }
];

function requiredFieldValidator(value) {
    if (value == null || value == undefined || !value.length) {
        return { valid: false, msg: "This is a required field" };
    } else {
        return { valid: true, msg: null };
    }
};

var options = {
    editable: true,
    enableAddRow: true,
    enableCellNavigation: true,
    asyncEditorLoading: false,
    autoEdit: true,
    enableExpandCollapse: true,
    rowHeight: 25
};

var sortcol = "parent_name";
var sortdir = 1;
var grid;
var data = [];
var groupItemMetadataProviderTrades = new Slick.Data.GroupItemMetadataProvider();
var dataView = new Slick.Data.DataView({ groupItemMetadataProvider:      groupItemMetadataProviderTrades });

dataView.onRowCountChanged.subscribe(function (e, args) {
    grid.updateRowCount();
    grid.render();
});

dataView.onRowsChanged.subscribe(function (e, args) {
    grid.invalidateRows(args.rows);
    grid.render();
});

function groupByParentAndSymbol() {
    dataViewTrades.setGrouping([
        {
            getter: "parent_name",
            formatter: function(g) {
                return "Parent:  " + g.value + "  <span style='color:green'>(" + g.count + " items)  Total: " + g.totals.sum.price + "</span>";
            },
            aggregators: [
                new Slick.Data.Aggregators.Sum("price")
            ],
            aggregateCollapsed: true
            ,lazyTotalsCalculation: true
        },
    {
        getter: "symbol",
        formatter: function(g) {
            return "Symbol:  " + g.value + "  <span style='color:green'>(" + g.count + " items)   Total: " + g.totals.sum.price + "</span>";
        },
        aggregators: [
            new Slick.Data.Aggregators.Sum("price")
        ],
        collapsed: true
        ,lazyTotalsCalculation: true
    }]);
};

grid = new Slick.Grid("#gridList", dataView, columns, options);
grid.registerPlugin(groupItemMetadataProviderTrades);
grid.setSelectionModel(new Slick.RowSelectionModel());

..... /*sorting support etc*/

 // use instead of the default formatter <---  removed not used.
 function sumTotalsFormatter(totals, columnDef) {
    var val = totals.sum && totals.sum[columnDef.field];
    //if (val != null) {
    //    return "total: " + ((Math.round(parseFloat(val) * 100) / 100));
    //}
    return "";
 }

// will be called on a button click (I didn't include the code as irrelevant)
var getDataList = function () {
    $.getJSON('/Home/GetData/', function (json) {
        data = json;
        dataView.beginUpdate();
        dataView.setItems(data);
        groupByParentAndSymbol();
        dataView.endUpdate();
        dataView.syncGridSelection(grid, true);
    });
 };

  getDataList();
```

});

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding displayTOtalsRow: false to the dataview solved my problem - the total rows are not shown now.

```
 var dataView = new Slick.Data.DataView({ groupItemMetadataProvider: groupItemMetadataProviderTrades, displayTotalsRow: false });
```

Comment: That answer seems to be wrong, looking at the DataView code on this [line](https://github.com/6pac/SlickGrid/blob/master/slick.dataview.js#L68) and we can see that the `displayTotalsRow` is a flag on the Group itself and isn't a flag in the DataView. Unless this existed in the previous version of SlickGrid, before the rewrite of the Grouping?

Answer (score 0):

To answer simply to your question... Just remove the `aggregators: [...]`, when I say remove you have 2 options, you can remove whatever is the array `[...]` or you could simply erase completely that object line (so removing completely the `aggregators[...]`).

Now if you want more explanation of how it works...Let's give you some definition so you'll understand better. An aggregate is a collection of items that are gathered together to form a total quantity. The total in question could be a sum of all the fields, an average or other type of aggregator you might define. So basically it's the action of regrouping by the column you chose and give the calculation result of the group. Alright now how does it work in the case of a SlickGrid? You need to define what kind of Aggregator you want to use (Avg, Sum, etc...) that goes inside your `function groupByParentAndSymbol()`, defining them will do the calculation **BUT** unless you attach it to the field, nothing will be displayed, so in the example you found it is very important to attach/bind this `groupTotalsFormatter: sumTotalsFormatter` to your columns definition, as for example:

```
...var columns = [{id: "cost", ...width: 90, groupTotalsFormatter: sumTotalsFormatter}, ...];
```

so let's recap... Once the Aggregator is define `new Slick.Data.Aggregators.Sum("cost")` it will do the calculation but unless it's bind to the field nothing will be displayed. As an extra option, the `aggregateCollapsed` (true/false) is to display the sub-total (avg, sum or whatever) inside or outside the group when you collapse.

Comment: I use the sum aggregators to calculate the sum but instead of the row I show the sum value at the grouping header row.

Comment: I believe that they are link together, if believe that if you remove the `aggregator:[]` then it won't show as an empty line but also won't calculate..it's like a catch 22..haha

Comment: Just figured it out.  var dataView = new Slick.Data.DataView({ groupItemMetadataProvider:      groupItemMetadataProviderTrades, displayTotalsRow: false });   The displayTotalsRow should not be in the options (didn't do anything I guess because I'm using the dataVIew), but in the dataView initialization.