# angular-slickgrid hide total rows when grouping

Tags: angular, angular-slickgrid

I'm using grouping with a sum aggregator to get it to work, but I don't actually care about the sums or any other info, I'm just interested in the grouping.
It's working fine but I'm getting an empty total row per group, which does not look great. Is there a way to get rid of it ?

Looking [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21735170/slickgrid-3-grouping-how-to-remove-totals-row) it seems like the solution is to pass displayTotalsRow: false to the dataView constructor, is that a possibility with angular-slickgrid ?

Thanks

Comment: No that flag is not available in Angular-Slickgrid, you can submit a PR, you can modify this [line](https://github.com/ghiscoding/Angular-Slickgrid/blob/master/src/app/modules/angular-slickgrid/models/gridOption.interface.ts#L120) to add your the `displayTotalsRow?: boolean` and modify this [line](https://github.com/ghiscoding/Angular-Slickgrid/blob/master/src/app/modules/angular-slickgrid/components/angular-slickgrid.component.ts#L736) to use it `new Slick.Data.DataView({ displayTotalsRow: this.gridOptions.dataView.displayTotalsRow, ...`

Comment: So I was about to look at adding this in Angular-Slickgrid and found out that the answer you looked at is completely wrong, the `displayTotalsRow` is a flag that exist in the Group Info as seen on this [line](https://github.com/6pac/SlickGrid/blob/master/slick.dataview.js#L68) and so this is already available in Angular-Slickgrid `grouping: { getter: 'title', displayTotalsRow: false, aggregators: [...], ...  }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SO answer you referenced in your question is wrong, the `displayTotalsRow` is not a flag that exist on the DataView but is instead a flag that exist in the Group Info (`grouping`) as seen on this [line](https://github.com/6pac/SlickGrid/blob/master/slick.dataview.js#L68) of the DataView (`slick.dataview.js`) and this is already available in Angular-Slickgrid `grouping: { getter: 'title', displayTotalsRow: false, aggregators: [...], ...  }`

```js
groupByDuration() {
    this.dataviewObj.setGrouping({
      getter: 'duration',
      formatter: (g) => `Duration: ${g.value} <span style="color:green">(${g.count} items)</span>`,
      aggregators: [
        new Aggregators.Avg('percentComplete'),
        new Aggregators.Sum('cost')
      ],
      comparer: (a, b) => Sorters.numeric(a.value, b.value, SortDirectionNumber.asc),
      aggregateCollapsed: false,
      lazyTotalsCalculation: true,
      displayTotalsRow: false, // <<-- HERE is the flag you want to use
    } as Grouping);

    // you need to manually add the sort icon(s) in UI
    this.angularGrid.filterService.setSortColumnIcons([{ columnId: 'duration', sortAsc: true }]);
    this.gridObj.invalidate(); // invalidate all rows and re-render
  }
```

or with Draggable Grouping

```js
initializeGrid {
  this.columnDefinitions = [
      {
        id: 'title', name: 'Title', field: 'title',
        width: 70, minWidth: 50,
        cssClass: 'cell-title',
        filterable: true,
        sortable: true,
        grouping: {
          getter: 'title',
          formatter: (g) => `Title: ${g.value}  <span style="color:green">(${g.count} items)</span>`,
          aggregators: [
            new Aggregators.Sum('cost')
          ],
          displayTotalsRow: false, // <<-- HERE is the flag you want to use
          aggregateCollapsed: false,
          collapsed: false
        }
      },
  ];
}
```

#### Grouping Interface

The Angular-Slickgrid TypeScript interface with all the possible flags/options can be seen [here](https://github.com/ghiscoding/Angular-Slickgrid/blob/master/src/app/modules/angular-slickgrid/models/grouping.interface.ts)

#### DataView

For further reference, and to prove that the flag isn't a valid DataView option, if you just look at the top of the `slick.dataview.js` file, you'll see right away in the class definition that there's only 2 available flags as acceptable DataView options (the `defaults` variable shown below). So taking a look at the internal does help sometimes.

```js
  function DataView(options) {
    var self = this;

    var defaults = {
      groupItemMetadataProvider: null,
      inlineFilters: false
    };
// ...
```

Comment: Hey, that does indeed work ! I looked through those files to try and find where to set it, but somehow I must have missed it in the file you linked, sorry about that.
Thanks for the help !

Comment: Glad I could help, and if you haven't done that yet, you can upvote my lib if you like it, that is all I ask in return ;)